# Ambiguity in "may not"

Tags: grammar

The ambiguity in "may not" can only be removed by context, right?

For example:

1. You may not play football in the garden = you must not/are not allowed to play football in the garden
2. This method may not be applicable in this case = It is possible that this method does not work in this case = It is likely that this method does not work in this case

Do I have the right understanding of "may not"?

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/may) clarifies the ways in which **may** is used. 3 - May you score many goals.

Comment: To soccer players and all other garden users: we're asking for a $15 donation towards the upkeed of the garden, especially the large lawn. You may not play football in the garden, but doubtless you will enjoy the improved plantings and facilities the monies will also allow. _Context is everything._

Comment: Thank you all:-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All modal verbs have two functions: one that modifies the "mode" of the verb and the other which expresses some possibility.

Comment: +1 ... but needs reference.